# any way to generate JNI files from .c and .h files?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, openssl

I compiled `Openssl` for android but I dont see how to access the functions from java. I think I need some kind of JNI files for that. Is there a way to generate the corresponding JNI files for the ***libssl.so*** and ***libcrypto.so*** from `Openssl` .c and .h files.

Comment: I think you must have header (.h ) file of compiled Openssl, If you have, with help of jni you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [swig](http://www.swig.org/). That should be able to generate the necessary Java and c-code, to allow you to call the native functions defined in the openssl header from Java.

You should simply be able to do:

```
swig openssl.h
```

And you will have some java classes representing the openssl.h interface, and you will have a c-wrapper that you need to crosscompile for android (like you have done for openssl).

On another node, you might want to take a look at [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). This is the crypto system included in android (and accessible through [javax.net.ssl](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/package-summary.html) - reading that link it sounds like openssl is included in android already).